# How do I access a param passed as 'action', since Rails uses that name internally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails app that integrates with other systems (which can't be changed), and I need to handle the case below:

A user is redirected to my app with a URL like:

http://myapp.com/index?action=signout

The problem is, I can't access this param through params[:action], since Rails uses that to keep track of the current action.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! I can just parse request.url myself, and that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

If its not passed inside the params hash, then you're probably out of luck. Perhaps it could be somehow remapped with a Metal/Rack app...